# Running python multiprocess for Image processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a python function that takes in an image path and outputs true or false depending whether the image is black or not. I want to process several images on the same machine and stop the process if even one of them is not black. I read a lot of multiprocessing in python, celery etc here,  but I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at [Pools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) to easily create processes on the fly. If you need to have some shared state, in this case a boolean indicating a non-black image has been found, look at [Managers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers).

Update: Here is an example of what I mean.

```
import multiprocessing.Manager as Manager
import multiprocessing.Pool as Pool

m = Manager()
p = Pool(processes=5)

state_info = m.dict()
state_info['image_found'] = False

def processImage(img):

    # ... Process Image ...

    if imageIsBlack(img):
        state_info['image_found'] = True
        p.terminate()

 p.apply(processImage, imageList)

 if state_info['image_found']:
     print 'There was a black image!!'
 else:
     print 'No black images were found.'
```

Comment: I have a working code for spawning my processes and it is working fine but I am not able to exit out if functions for the process return False.

Comment: If you are using Pools then you can just use terminate. I added an update to show you how. If you are sub-classing Process then be sure to check that 'image_found' is False before beginning the computation.

Comment: Thanks for the code example but your example will raise an error becuase 'p' is not recognized as a variable in the scope of function 'processImage' and we cannot call p.terminate() from inside this function. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Also this function has no idea about state_info dict.

Comment: Since p is defined outside the function it has a global scope. If you try to modify p, then you need to add `global p` at the beginning of processImage, but otherwise the above code should work.

Comment: Ah I see . . . Since I am on windows, I have to use the if __name__=="__main__" to watchguard against nested imports. Thus my global scope is different from where I initialize manager and processes.

Answer (score 2):

Finally this works nicely for me. Copied it from an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286235/multiple-threads-in-python/6286343#6286343). For illustration purpose I have replaced my _isImgNonBlack function and the image sequence as a list of 0's and 1's, where 0 being a black image and 1 non-black image.

```
import multiprocessing

def isImgNonBlack(result_queue, imgSeq):
    for img in imgSeq:
        # If a non-black is found put a result
        if img==1:
            result_queue.put(1)

    # else put a zero as the result
    result_queue.put(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processs = []
    result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    nbProc = 20

    # making a fake list of images with 
    # 10,000 0's follwed by a single 1
    images = [0 for n in range(10000)]
    images.append(1)

    for n in range(nbProc): # start processes crawling for the result
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=isImgNonBlack, args=[result_queue, images])
        process.start()
        processs.append(process)
        print 'Starting Process : %s' % process

    result = result_queue.get() # waits until any of the proccess have `.put()` a result

    for process in processs: # then kill them all off
        process.terminate()

    # finally print the result
    print "Seq have a non black img: %s" % result
```