# multithreading with Jython in ImageJ

Tags: multithreading, jython, imagej

I have written an image analysis pipeline using Jython in ImageJ. I am interested in using multithreading to speed up the process. Basically the pipeline processes multiple images (in the same way) and I would like to concurrently process the images. 
I have seen an example using Python and multiprocessing ([Running python multiprocess for Image processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781895/running-python-multiprocess-for-image-processing)). This is not possible with Jython. Any help on how to proceed would be much appreciated (I am completely new to multithreading)

Answer (score 1):

The Definitive Guide to Jython book has a chapter on concurrency, which provides a very thorough answer to this question:

https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Concurrency/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i found, in case it is helpful. Note - on my computer this did not significantly decrease the execution time.

```
from java.util.concurrent import Callable
from java.util.concurrent import Executors, TimeUnit

# get user to select a directory and list all file names
settings = IJ.getDirectory("Choose a Directory")
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(settings):
   for filename in filenames:
        SITES.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

# function for shutting down the pool - taken from: 
# http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/Concurrency.html
def shutdown_and_await_termination(pool, timeout):
  pool.shutdown()
  try:
    if not pool.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS):
        pool.shutdownNow()
        if (not pool.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)):
            print >> sys.stderr, "Pool did not terminate"
  except InterruptedException, ex:
    # (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
    pool.shutdownNow()
    # Preserve interrupt status
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt()

# function that will change all images listed - in this case convert to 8bit
def help(imp):
  conv = ImageConverter(imp)
  conv.convertToGray8() 

# make a callable interface where image will be each image in the list
# in this case each image will be opened, the help function run, which 
# converts to 8bit and then the image is displayed on screen
class imageConverter(Callable):
  def __init__(self):
    self.test = image

  def call(self):
    imp = IJ.openImage(self.test)
    help(imp)
    imp.show()

# define the number of threads
MAX_CONCURRENT = 2
pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_CONCURRENT)
# define the task to do in a multithreaded way
imageConverter = [imageConverter() for image in SITES]

# use all defined threads to convert the images
pool.invokeAll(imageConverter)

shutdown_and_await_termination(pool, 5)
```