# Asynchronous file distribution with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, shutil

I'm new to coding and to python. I tried to create a code that will distribute files over the network, problem is, it iterates through a list I made, and distributes one after another. Only when the first location gets the files, just then it will start with the second distribution.

This is the code I wrote:

```
from shutil import copytree

source = r"O:\versions"

Eilat = r"\\eilat-zrv\c$\version"
BeerSheba = r"\\beer-sheba-zrv\c$\version"
Ashdod = r"\\ashdod-zrv\c$\version"
Rehovot = r"\\rehovot-zrv\c$\version"
Rishon = r"\\rishon-zrv\c$\version"
TelAviv = r"\\dizingof-zrv\c$\version"
Netanya = r"\\netanya-zrv\c$\version"
RamatIshay = r"\\ramaty-zrv\c$\version"
Haifa = r"\\haifa-zrv\c$\version"



DestList = [Eilat, BeerSheba, Ashdod, Rehovot, Rishon, TelAviv, Netanya, RamatIshay, Haifa]

def Copy_funct(i):
    for i in DestList:
         copytree(source, i)

Copy_funct(DestList)
```

How can I make it distribute simultaneously??

Comment: Rephrasing: "how do I spawn threads/sub-processes in Python". Would that be a fair interpretation?

Comment: Some useful insights at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286235/multiple-threads-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Using threads it would look sth like this:

```
import threading

def Copy_funct(DestList):
  threads = [ threading.Thread(target=lambda dest=dest: copytree(source, dest))
              for dest in DestList ]
  for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
  for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

EDIT:

A bit of explanation:

Threading is a way of splitting your program into several threads of action which all are pursued in parallel by the computer; if one thread has to wait for something (typically I/O), another thread can continue its own task.  Doing stuff in a parallel fashion opens up a large Box of Pandora of possible bugs you probably never have heard of if you haven't done concurrency before, and I can't go into detail here.  But I think your usecase is simple enough to not hit such problems.

The first statement in my function builds a list of threads (a "thread" is represented by an object in Python).  These threads are told upon creation what their task will be (using the parameter `target`).  The argument given is a `lambda` closure; this way I can easily pass information (`dest`) into the closure.  Basically, what I pass to parameter `target` is a function that, when called, will do that `copytree()` call with the correct parameters for one of your tasks.

The second statement is a loop over all threads and just starts each.  Before that they are just unstarted threads, like post-it notes with ToDo reminders but without an action taking place.  With `start()` I start each thread; that starting takes virtually no time, the call to start them will return immediately, so I can start all threads practically at the same moment.  I have no direct control over when they actually start doing their thing; the first may have already begun its work when the last is being started.

The third statement also is a loop over all threads and uses `join()` to wait for their finishing.  It doesn't matter which threads finishes first or last, I will first wait for the first thread, then for the second, etc.  If the second actually finishes earlier than the first, this is no problem, it will just be a finished thread which hasn't been joined yet.  It will be joined (and then properly cleaned up) by the `join` in the second iteration of the second loop.

I hope this explains it enough to be useful for you.  Feel free to suggest further improvements on this answer if still vital things are unclear.

Comment: Wow. I could not have figured that out myself. Pretty sure this would solve OPs problem.

Comment: Hi,Tried this code over Python IDLE. doesn't seem to work. give me an invalid syntax error.

Comment: Maybe someone can understand how I actually use threading. cause I dont have a clue. this will definetly help!

Comment: can you paste your syntax error code into pastebin or so, so i can have a look at it?

Comment: I'm using IDLE so it just write "Invalid Syntax"

Comment: I've seen the pasted code in the "answer" below and found two problems, one is my fault:  There was a closing parenthesis missing after `copytree(source, dest)`, so it has to be `copytree(source, dest))` instead.  I fixed that in my post above.  The other problem is your indentation in the two `for` loops.  Please compare that with my post.

Comment: I added a part explaining the mechanism behind the threading in brief.  But I encourage you to seek further advice on that topic otherwise you are bound to run into the typical concurrency problems sooner or later.