# Searching throughout telnet output result while doing parallel telnet to multiple network devices

Tags: telnetlib

I am trying to find a string (e.g.: `ZNTS`) from telnet output to a host.

I want to telnet to multiple hosts at the same time because waiting to finish from host to host takes a long time. The host can not response fast enough, so I need to sleep after every command line.

Below is my code:

```
import sys
import telnetlib
import time

MXK_LIST = ['172.16.32.15',
        '172.16.33.30',
        '192.168.55.3',
        '192.168.52.3',
        '192.168.54.3',
        '192.168.42.25',
        '192.168.43.3',
        '192.168.44.3',
        '192.168.45.3',
        '192.168.46.3',
        '192.168.47.3',
        '192.168.48.3',
        '192.168.49.9']

 TOTAL_MXK = len(MXK_LIST)

 ZNTS = str(sys.argv[1])
 DEBUG = str(sys.argv[2])

 username = "admin"
 password = "4n0cmek0n9net"

 I = 0
 C = 0
 print "\n Finding ZNTS = " + ZNTS
 print "\n It will take around 5 minutes to complete the searching !!\n"

 for MXK in MXK_LIST: 
     I = I + 1
     OUTPUT = ""
     try:
         tn = telnetlib.Telnet(MXK)
     except:
         print "Bad Connection. Please verify IP again."
         sys.exit(0)
     tn.read_until(b"login: ",1)
     tn.write(username + "\n")
     time.sleep(5)
     tn.read_until(b"password: ",1)
     tn.write(password + "\n")
     time.sleep(5)
     OUTPUT = tn.read_until(b">",1)
     if DEBUG == 1: print OUTPUT
     time.sleep(5)
     tn.write("onu showall 1" + "\n")
     time.sleep(5)
     tn.read_until(b"[no] ",1)
     tn.write(b"yes" + "\n")
     time.sleep(15)
     OUTPUT = tn.read_until(b"quit",1)
     time.sleep(5)
     if DEBUG == 1: print OUTPUT
     tn.write("A" + "\n")
     time.sleep(5)
     OUTPUT = tn.read_until(b">",1)
     if DEBUG == 1: print OUTPUT
     tn.write("exit\n")
     if ZNTS in OUTPUT:
           print str(I) + "/" + str(TOTAL_MXK) + " : FOUND " + ZNTS + " IN " + MXK
           C = C + 1
     else:
           print str(I) + "/" + str(TOTAL_MXK) + " : NOT FOUND " + ZNTS + " IN " + MXK
     print "\n"+ZNTS + " is found in " + str(C) + " MXK"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You didn't ask a question or clearly explained your issue, therefore readers can't quickly see if they can help you or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to spawn a thread for each telnet session and parallelize the search that way.

Check out the multi-thread sample code here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286235/multiple-threads-in-python
```